# How could I dynamically manipulate with elements by inputs?

Tags: javascript

In javascript I am able to add new buttons, but I don't know how could I manipulate with them in sense that change their width and height by type in the parameter in inputs. In the code below changes are applied on each button I've create, but that should be possible for every single button to be different.

```js
var i = 0;
function buttonClick() {
  i++;
document.getElementById('number').value = "Button" + i;

const addbuton = document.getElementById('addbuton');
const a = document.getElementById('dropdown-content');

const button1 = document.createElement("button");
button1.setAttribute("id", document.getElementById('number').value);
button1.setAttribute("class","name");

const body = document.getElementById('preview');             

button1.innerHTML = document.getElementById('number').value;
button1.style.display = "block";
button1.style.width = "100px";  
button1.style.height = "32px";

body.appendChild(button1);

var apply = document.getElementById("apply");

apply.addEventListener("click", function() {

button1.style.width = document.getElementById("width").value; 
button1.style.height = document.getElementById("height").value;
})

};

function myFunction() {
  const element = document.activeElement.id;
  document.getElementById("output-element").innerHTML = element;
};
```

```css
.input {
  display: inline-grid;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<body onclick="myFunction()">
<div class="container">

    <div id="preview">
      <div class="input">
        <label for="lname">Width</label>
        <input type="text" id="width" name="width" value="px" autocomplete="off">

        <label for="lname">Height</label>
        <input type="text" id="height" name="height" value="px" autocomplete="off">
        <button id="apply">Apply</button>
        <input type="text" for="addbuton" id="number" value="" style="display: none;">
        <input type="button" onclick="buttonClick();" id="addbuton" value="Add Button">
      </div>

      <p>Active element ID: <em id="output-element"></em></p>
    </div>
    </div>  
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you are trying to apply styles to the most recently clicked button. In that case, you can use radio buttons. They are displayed in the following snippet for demonstration purposes; to hide them, use CSS `display: none;` or other tricks.

Inside the `addNewButton` function your (`buttonClick`), we will create a new radio  button along with its corresponding normal button; a link between them will be kept using a property (`linkedButton`). Also, when clicked, the button will change the radio's `checked` state to `true`.

```js
function addNewButton() {

    /* ... */

    // Create/Get elements.
    const button = document.createElement('button');
    const radio = document.createElement('input');
    const list = document.getElementById('list');

    /* ... */

    button.onclick = function () { // Event handler for button.
        radio.checked = true;
    };

    /* ... */

    radio.linkedButton = button; // Backlink to corresponding button.

    /* ... */

    list.appendChild(item); // Add the new pair to the DOM.
}
```

When the `Apply` button is clicked, we query the only radio which is checked at that moment. Then, we trace back and style its corresponding button.

```js
apply.addEventListener('click', function () {
    const radio = document.querySelector('[name="recently-clicked"]:checked');
    const button = radio.linkedButton;

    button.style.width = document.getElementById('width').value;
    button.style.height = document.getElementById('height').value;
});
```

Also, note that:

- Always name your functions and variables properly. This helps a lot in debugging.
- `<label>`'s `for=""` value should be another element's `id`, not its `name`.
- If you're using some kind of a form, use a `<form>` element.

```js
var i = 0;

function addNewButton() {
  const numberValue = `Button${++i}`;
  const button = document.createElement('button');
  const radio = document.createElement('input');
  const item = document.createElement('div');
  const list = document.getElementById('list');

  document.getElementById('number').value = numberValue;

  button.setAttribute('id', numberValue);
  button.setAttribute('class', 'name');
  button.innerHTML = numberValue;
  button.style.display = 'block';
  button.style.width = '100px';
  button.style.height = '32px';
  button.onclick = function() {
    radio.checked = true;
  };

  radio.type = 'radio';
  radio.name = 'recently-clicked';
  radio.linkedButton = button;
  radio.checked = list.childElementCount === 0;

  item.setAttribute('class', 'item');
  item.appendChild(button);
  item.appendChild(radio);

  list.appendChild(item);
}

const apply = document.getElementById('apply');
apply.addEventListener('click', function() {
  const radio = document.querySelector('[name="recently-clicked"]:checked');
  const button = radio.linkedButton;

  button.style.width = document.getElementById('width').value;
  button.style.height = document.getElementById('height').value;
});
```

```css
.input {
  display: inline-grid;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
}

#list {
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.item {
  display: flex;
  gap: 10px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div id="preview">
      <div class="input">
        <label for="width">Width</label>
        <input type="text" id="width" name="width" value="10px" autocomplete="off">
        <label for="height">Height</label>
        <input type="text" id="height" name="height" value="20px" autocomplete="off">
        <button id="apply">Apply</button>
        <input type="text" for="addbuton" id="number" value="" style="display: none;">
        <input type="button" onclick="addNewButton();" id="addbuton" value="Add Button">
      </div>
      <div id="list"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer it's very helpful for me. Just one more question, does it possible that when I check radio button, button's parameters get load in inputs? :)

Comment: If you mean the button's height and width, you can get them directly from the button, as they're also properties of it itself: `height = radio.linkedButton.styles.height`.